# Advantages of Declaring Subclasses using Base Class Constructor in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, subclass, base-class

Are there any advantages of declaring and initializing a subclass using a base class constructor method with parameters:

```
class BaseClass(object):
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

class SubClass(BaseClass):
  def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
    BaseClass.__init__(self, a, b)
    # or super().
    self.c = c
    self.d = d

newSubClassInstance = SubClass("one", "two", "three", "four")
```

Over not using parameters at all and just initializing as follows:

```
class BaseClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = " "
    self.b = " "

class SubClass(BaseClass):
  def __init__(self):
    self.c = " "
    self.d = " "

newSubClassInstance = SubClass()
newSubClassInstance.a = "one"
newSubClassInstance.b = "two"
newSubClassInstance.c = "three"
newSubClassInstance.d = "four"
```

Or is it just up to how one intends to write and use this code within a program? I'm asking mostly about expectations though; would one be better over another if asked to create this particular task in Python, for example?

Comment: `newSubClass` should be `newInstance` because it’s an _object_ of type `SubClass` and not a class. Other than that, both versions of the code achieve the same. If you’re familiar with private and protected class members in other programming languages (e.g. C++ or Java) then constructors make more sense, but for Python it doesn’t much matter either way. (Also, please call `super().__init__()` in your second example to ensure complete initialization.)

Comment: Okay, I made those edits to the question ... thank you, makes sense!

Comment: I would argue that there is lot of advantages of using base constructor. First is readability of this code, just create object with it's constructor and it's done. Second is that it is ensured that you provided all arguments, you won't forget to initialise something. Third is that you can do a lot of things in constructor, for example you can read configuration data from file. Using it gives you opportunity to do such operations without complicating usage of such class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely instantiate and setup you class in the `__init__` method. When the class is (created and) initilaized it should, if possible, be ready to be used. That is what one would expect from a class.

For some situations, e.g. when trying to mimic an immutable, the values should never be updated after the `__init__()` call. There is also a penality in updating after initialization, as an update may need to trigger other changes. Think of a GUI where one of the inputs is the size of a window being drawn. If that is set after the Window first appear, it has to be redrawn.

Also, your second approach is bad in another way; you do not even have the `self.a` and `self.b` after the `__init__()` call, as you never call `BaseClass.__init__()`. This you should always do when inheriting and overriding `__init__()`.

You should also consider replacing your explicit call to `BaseClass` with a call to `super()` (as you have written as a comment) as that will handle multiple inheritance better.